# Repeat block of div with different data from server

Tags: jquery, html, api

I am learning how to consume api and using its data, so i tried creating a news feed as practical. I have been able to get the get the response from the server, placed it appropriately in my card (div).

```
$.ajax({
        url:'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ng&category=health&apiKey=06008e50d7cf47e68f9c9d084b9ed5e0',
        datatype:'jsonp',
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);

            $.each(result.articles, function(i, item){

                console.log( i + '<br>' + item.title + '<br>' + item.content);
                var news_title = item.title;
                var news_content = item.content;
                var news_image = item.urlToImage;

                $('.card').append(`
                <div class="card-header">
                        <p> ${news_title} </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p id="news-content"> ${news_content} </p>
                    </div>

                `)
```

I want each the cards(siblings inclusive) to be repeated after each other in an inline-block format.

Note: the post title carries #0B486B colour

[image]

Comment: Its a part of HTML, jQuery code is fine I believe. You need to wrap the `card_header` and `card_content` divs into another div with a class like `news-element` and in the CSS define its property to **float:left**.

Comment: @ Kundan Singh Chouhan It gives the same output as the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a div (let's say .container) and in that div you should append the a div with .card + .d-inline-block classes. 
Based on your code it should be something like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ng&category=health&apiKey=06008e50d7cf47e68f9c9d084b9ed5e0',
        datatype:'jsonp',
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);

            $.each(result.articles, function(i, item){

                console.log( i + '<br>' + item.title + '<br>' + item.content);
                var news_title = item.title;
                var news_content = item.content;
                var news_image = item.urlToImage;

                $('.container').append(`
                <div class="card d-inline-block">
                  <div class="card-header">
                        <p> ${news_title} </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p id="news-content"> ${news_content} </p>
                    </div>

                `)
```

---

Old (and general) answer:

Not sure if i understood you well, but it seems you can use bootstrap class for [floating](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/float/) in order to get the desire effect.

Since you haven't tag CSS you can achieve that with jQuery like that

```
 $('.card').addClass('float-left');
```

$('.card').addClass('d-inline');
With CSS you can add this:

```
.card {display: inline-block;}
```

OR

```
.card {float: left;}
```

EDIT

Bootstrap hold class for inline display... So:

```
 $('.card').addClass('d-inline');
```

OR

```
 $('.card').addClass('d-inline-block');
```

Comment: All that is what i have done and its still the same

here is my css code for  .card

```
.card{
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    background-color:#fff; 
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 3px grey;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Are you generating new div.card every time or appending to the one div.card? you should do the first one in order to make it work as you want.

Comment: I want new div.card to be generated per post title and content.

Comment: This works fine. Thanks for your time. Now i realized my mistake. I ought to append the card to the holder. Thanks @A. Meshu